# Is it possible to create a 4"x4" channel through concrete using acid?

Tags: concrete

I'm trying to figure out a possible way to eat through concrete without damage pex tubing inside (its a radiant heated slab). Is there any way using some type of acid (hydrofluoric, muriatic ) to eat a 4" wide and 4" deep channel through the slab that could be tapped out with a blunt chisel? Pex tubing is resistant to most acids so wouldn't be damaged.

Secondly would this be cost effective (under $1000), I need this channel to be about 71 feet long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and no. Acid isn't controllable that way.

And hydrofluoric acid is really nasty stuff.